# Desktop Sharing not working when upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, gnome, remote-desktop, vnc, sharing

Just upgraded (reinstalled, because upgrading messed up my whole system) from 11.04 to 11.10 and Desktop sharing simply doesn't work anymore.

Under the Desktop Sharing Preferences I enabled the following options:

- Allow other users to view your desktop
- Allow other users to control your desktop
- Require the user to enter this password (and set up one)
- Show Notification Area Icon: Always

I set up the notification area icon to always show after I'd noticed my PC wasn't accepting VNC connections on port 5900.

After setting up the preferences like described above, imho the expected behavior would be a Desktop  Sharing icon showing up next to the clock. The icon does not show and PC still not responding to VNC connections.

Any guidance appreciated.

Thiago

Answer (score 1):

Yep yep, it's not just you, it's an issue many are currently waking up to.

Somethings wrong with the Desktop Sharing in 11.10 ...

Here's some links to other threads working on that very issue.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861148
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/174568

If your Internet connection uses a static IP address, then theres a workaround that seems to be working... oddly enough, just by changing to Dynamic in your ipv4 connection settings, rebooting, and then changing back to manual entry of your IP. It's a flaky workaround, but its working IF you use a static IP address.

(Right click on the network icon top-right, edit connections, click edit on your connection, under ipv4 change to dynamic or automatic whatever, save, restart, then change the settings back)

I however use a dynamically assigned IP address, and that workaround doesnt work for me.
Ho-hum... hope they fix this soon... physically driving to work is starting to suck.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have seen to share (after you have done the above you mentioned in `vino-preferences` is that you need to have the person you want to share with in your Empathy messenger. After configuring `vino-preferences` you can use empathy to share. Already tested which is also the only way to enable sharing with Empathy. So it works both ways.